# OpenLDAP __db.00# file permission reset to root

Tags: centos, openldap, ownership

I have an openLDAP installed on my CentOS 7 VM. The user that is running the openLDAP is `ldap:ldap`.

If the server has an unexpected shutdown, for whatever reason, files listed below get reset from the `ldap` user to the `root` user.

```
__db.001
__db.002
__db.003
```

If there is a graceful shutdown, this issue doesn't occur.

Obviously with this issue, the `slapd` service cannot start, until I manually change the permission and reboot the server.

The problem is, I then have to reboot my entire server stack, as network drives do not mount, and apps wont start without the appropriate users etc.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?